# Ruby Uninitialized constant error when gem is run outside of bundle exec

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a simple gem that creates an MD5 from a string.

```
module SimpleMD5
  require 'digest/md5'

  def self.md5_string(string)
    Digest::MD5.hexdigest(string)
  end
end
```

Running `bundle exec bin/console` and calling the method works fine

`require 'simple_md5'`

`SimpleMD5.md5_string('test')`

`=> 098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6`

Once the gem is built using `rake build` and `rake install` using the IRB console and the same example above I get an error.

`NameError: uninitialized constant SimpleMD5::Digest`

Am I missing a step when the gem is built?

Comment: `Moldule`? Please pay more attention to details and be more respectful to people who are trying to help you, like @tadman.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the module definition, so use this pattern:

```
require 'digest/md5'

module SimpleMD5
  def md5_string(string)
    Digest::MD5.hexdigest(string)
  end

  extend self
end
```

The `SimpleMD5` name is not generated automatically, you must declare it somewhere.

Here `extend self` means you can mix-in the module with `include SimpleMD5` as well as just use it straight-up as you do in your example.

Don't forget two things: In Ruby `return` is implicit, there's no need to use that unless you're exiting your function early, and MD5 is a pretty terrible hashing algorithm for 2016. Unless you're using it for backwards compatibility, use something better like SHA256 or SHA512.

Comment: `module_function` is more applicable here instead of `extend self`. I personally can’t imagine any use-case that uses `include` pattern.

Comment: @mudasobwa It's very common in Ruby to use "mix-ins" as `include SimpleMD5` allows you to use `md5_string` without having to prefix it all the time.

Comment: I was told that `extend SimpleMD5` is permitted too for that. `extend self` here just does not follow neither DRY no SRP.

Comment: @mudasobwa That's a subjective opinion. I've seen `extend self` used in many, many projects because it's simple and offers options. Of course there's [other ways of doing this](http://idiosyncratic-ruby.com/8-self-improvement.html), like the `module_function` method you mention, but this does the job here.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve my issue. Even with `extend self` I still receive the error `NameError: uninitialized constant SimpleMD5::Digest` when I install the gem locally and try to use it through IRB.

Comment: The `extend self` part is just a convenience, not a requirement. I don't know why this isn't working for you, as it runs just fine [on CodePad](http://codepad.org/lcITO6LH). Make sure you've got the `require` loading properly.

Comment: No doubt the code works, when I run `bundle exec bin/console` I can run the code as on CodePad without issue. Once the gem is built and installed is when the error occurs.

Comment: @MaxKerman Do you have simple tests bundled with your gem? Something this small and self-contained should be pretty easy to exercise and verify that it's working. If you have tests, see if [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org) is happy with it. That's usually a very good way to find problems early.